# How to change bootstrap 4 column order on mobile layout?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, multiple-columns

I want to put in a certain order the columns's elements when I resize to mobile. The code is:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">5</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">6</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">7</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">8</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">9</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">10</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">11</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">12</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">13</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">14</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">15</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I resize, the order I would like to be:

> [1]
>
> [2]
>
> [6]
>
> [7]
>
> [11]
>
> [12]
>
> [3]
>
> [8]
>
> [13]
>
> [4]
>
> [9]
>
> [14]
>
> [5]
>
> [10]
>
> [15]

I have seen that `flex-column-reverse flex-md-row` could be used, but this doesn't solve my problem.

What should I do to get the order I want when I resize?

Comment: Well, one trick to this is create another `div` that contains that particular order, then only display it on mobile, while hiding the other `div`

Comment: as I understand you want to relocate content on mobile , so you need to change it manualy , there is no automatic way to change content for you , even thought you will put numbers there. well you may write javascript function to automatic generate html structure for you depends on window size

Comment: @CarlBinalla, how could I do this? :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change in your html code to achieve result, try to use css grid to manage ordering of the item. Please check this code.

```css
.row
{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 50px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 50px);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .row {
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
 }
 .col-sm-1:nth-of-type(1) {
  order: 1;
 }
 .col-sm-1:nth-of-type(2) {
  order: 2;
 }
 .col-sm-1:nth-of-type(6) {
  order: 3;
 }
 .col-sm-1:nth-of-type(7) {
  order: 4;
 }
 .col-sm-1:nth-of-type(11) {
  order: 5;
 }
 .col-sm-1:nth-of-type(12) {
  order: 6;
 }
 .col-sm-1:nth-of-type(3) {
  order: 7;
 }
 .col-sm-1:nth-of-type(8) {
  order: 8;
 }
 .col-sm-1:nth-of-type(13) {
  order: 9;
 }
 .col-sm-1:nth-of-type(4) {
  order: 10;
 }
 .col-sm-1:nth-of-type(9) {
  order: 11;
 }
 .col-sm-1:nth-of-type(14) {
  order: 12;
 }
 .col-sm-1:nth-of-type(5) {
  order: 13;
 }
 .col-sm-1:nth-of-type(10) {
  order: 14;
 }
 .col-sm-1:nth-of-type(15) {
  order: 15;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">5</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">6</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">7</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">8</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">9</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">10</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">11</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">12</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">13</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">14</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">15</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are okay in creating another `div` for mobile, here's a way on how will you do it using the [display utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container d-none d-sm-block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">5</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">6</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">7</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">8</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">9</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">10</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">11</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">12</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">13</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">14</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">15</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container d-sm-none d-flex align-items-center justify-content-around">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>15</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's my fault that when I wrote the post, I arranged in a raw the order I want, not in a column as I want. The code you gave me puts the elements in a row when I resize.

Comment: Whatever is the content of your question is the only thing that will be answered, as we can't really guess what you really want. As per the question, the numbers are arranged in a single line below the `col-sm` breakpoint. If it is not what you want, I really suggest editing the question to better portray what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    sidebar
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 ">
    main
</div>
```

And then you can use media queries and
Inside media queries

```
.row{ display:flex; flex-flow: coulmn-reverse: }
```

I hope this would help

Answer (score -1):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1 order-sm-0 order-0">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 order-sm-0 order-0">2</div>

    <div class="col-sm-1 order-sm-0 order-3">3</div>

    <div class="col-sm-1 order-sm-0 order-4">4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 order-sm-0 order-5">5</div>

    <div class="col-sm-1 order-sm-0 order-1">6</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 order-sm-0 order-1">7</div>

    <div class="col-sm-1 order-sm-0 order-3">8</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 order-sm-0 order-4">9</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 order-sm-0 order-5">10</div>

    <div class="col-sm-1 order-sm-0 order-2">11</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 order-sm-0 order-2">12</div>

    <div class="col-sm-1 order-sm-0 order-3">13</div>

    <div class="col-sm-1 order-sm-0 order-4">14</div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 order-sm-0 order-5">15</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
order block
```

Here `order-sm-0` class will neutral order in `sm` and above breakpoint. bootstrap has following order class helper https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#order

I have organised order class in following sequence

```
order-0 => [1], [2]     
order-1 => [6], [7]    
order-2 => [11], [12]    
order-3 => [3], [8], [13]   
order-4 => [4], [9], [14]  
order-5 => [5], [10], [15]
```

Comment: It does order how I want when I resize. But why the order is changed on desktop size?